# WSO2 Enterprise Integration: POST request give CORS Error

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have Restful APIs. I want to use WSO2 EI. I use WSO2 Integration Studio. When I do that all GET request works well. But POST request gets CORS error when I send request from the front-end (ReactJs). Also request with parameters do not pass to backend either. Is there any extra configuration need to be done?
[image: post request]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSO2 EI V7.x.x or V8.x.x, just add the following configuration to the `<EI_HOME>/runtime/microesb/conf/deployment.toml` file.

```
[synapse_properties]
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.enabled' = "true"
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.Access-Control-Allow-Origin' = "http://127.0.0.1:5500, http://localhost:5500"
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.Access-Control-Allow-Methods' = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS"
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.Access-Control-Allow-Headers' = "content-type, Accept, Authorization"
```

Change the Allowed origin, methods, and headers according to your need.

For WSO2 EI v6.x.x, check out https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Enabling+CORS+for+Data+Services+